# can we attach outgoing email action from flow into case feed?

Tags: email

I have implemented one scenario in which, when case is created via email or via manually, the Email will sent to the case contact via email Action.

That generated email in flow via action is not shown in case feed.

how can I attach  email action in case feed?

What should I do to include all email regarding one case into related case feed?

Comment: [related ideas](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AzbgIAC)